# <audio> not playing on https with Android browsers

Tags: android, html, html5-audio, opera-mobile, dolphin-browser

So, I'm maintaining the main page of an archive located [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28501521/GeneralArchive/RenneQuest/RenneArchive.html), where an audio element gets inserted with a randomly chosen RELATIVE link to an audio file. It plays the audio fine on desktop browsers, but it fails to play the audio on Android mobile browsers, like Dolphin Jetpack and Opera Mobile. Code that creates the audio element:

```
var d = document, $ = function(a){ return d.querySelector(a); }, o, a, b
    audios = ["htmlfiles/Log4/Audio Files/1339041384627.png.audio02.ogg",
    "htmlfiles/Log4/Audio Files/1339039129463.png.audio01.ogg",
    "htmlfiles/Log5/Audio Files/s05_08.png.audio01.ogg",
    "htmlfiles/Log6/Audio files/s06_19.png.audio01.ogg",
    "htmlfiles/Log7P1/Audio Files/s07_01.png.audio01.ogg",
    "htmlfiles/Log10/Audio files/1343286991927.png.audio01.ogg",
    "htmlfiles/Log10/Audio files/1343293678793.gif.audio02.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1343888663849.png.audio02.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1345719774310.png.audio01.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1346311163394.png.audio02.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1346919244950.png.audio02.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1347509276756.png.audio01.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1347515470408.png.audio02.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1348079866537.png.audio01.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1349419913717.png.audio01.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1350030423418.png.audio01.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1350033736151.png.audio02.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1351231673165.png.audio01.ogg",
    "AudioFiles/1343870457212.png.audio01.ogg"];

/*The code above is in the head tag, the one below is at the end of the body tag*/

window.opera && (o = $('div:not([id])')).parentNode.removeChild(o);
var audio = d.createElement("audio")/*, source = d.createElement("source")*/;
audio.autoplay = audio.controls = audio.loop = true;
// source.type = "audio/ogg";
audio.src =/* source.src =*/ audios[Math.floor(Math.random() * audios.length)];
// audio.appendChild(source);
audio.appendChild(d.createTextNode("Your browser does not support the audio element."));
$("div#container").insertBefore(audio, $("div#container > div:last-of-type").nextElementSibling);
```

I'd like to know what can cause such behaviour. I've tested both mobile browsers on w3schools' try-it page, and their audio worked fine there. I'm suspecting it could be something with the https protocol.

Edit: I've reported the bug for Opera through the report wizard, and for Mobotap via an email with a link to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just getting rid of this zombie. In the end, I think updating the browsers at a later point fixed it.